# Is there a way to update the running Siddhi Application

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am using a Siddhi 5.1. I using Siddhi Manager to create and run the application. I want to update the running application with the new application. Currently, I stop the running application, create new runtime and run the new application.

But, the problem with this approach is any data in in-memory storage use like named widnows is lost.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible using RESTful API. Check here [Siddhi app api](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/rest-guides/siddhi-app-api/)